# I want hidden field value from c# to my javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, hiddenfield

i have hidden field run at server and i set value to it in my c# code and when i click a button i want that value transfer to my javascript or jquery , and also that button is in the update panel. so no postback occurs. i called it by registerstartupscript but didnt work , here is my c# code

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     // Convert Image to byte[]
     image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
     byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

     // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
     base64String = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
}

hidImgQR.Value = base64String;
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "myScript", getImgQR();", true);
```

in jQUERY

```
function getImgQR() 
{   
    alert($("input[id$=hidImgQR]").val());      
}
```

i have tried many different way but it doesnt work, may be because of update panel it doesnt take latest value but only the defalut value i have assigned ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have Hidden field control

```
<asp:HiddenField id="fileId" runat="server" value='Nishant' />
```

JavaScript Code which will return hidden field Value

```
document.getElementById("<%= fileId.ClientID %>").value;
```

**Note** You can also make `ClientIDMode="Static"` use this property for your control and retrieve it by id itself 'fileId' ForInstance:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="fileId" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" value='Nishant' />
```

and use JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById("fileId").value;
```

It will also return Nishant but Id will be static. Use only `ClientIDMode="Static` when you are sure that no one control has same Id.

Runnable Asp.Net Code
http://runnable.com/UjsLAmP-yM0VAADp/asp-net-how-to-get-server-control-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this

```
$('#' + '<%= hidImgQR.ClientID %>').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
   alert($("<%= hidImgQR.ClientID %>").val());
```

call button's click inside `pageLoad()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function pageLoad() { 
    $("#yourbtn").click(function(){
    alert($("<%= hidImgQR.ClientID %>").val());
   });
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: i have also tried that , problem is not of not getting the value, problem is not getting the right value , i think may be because of update panel

Comment: I think,  you are using in `document.ready()`. Use it inside `pageload()` of jquey if you have update panel

Comment: i m using none of them, i just call the function getImgQR() when button is clicked

Comment: write that function inside `pageload()` of Jquery